# Validate command using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, command

I'm new to WPF and MVVM so bear with me.

Basically, I am creating an application to enable users to enter their organisation details into a database.

within my WPF application I'm creating, I have a `View Model` that contains `properties`, `commands` and `entity framework` methods (I know this isn't the correct way to use MVVM, but I'm learning slowly how to achieve it).

On one of my views, it is a tab control, allowing a user to enter different organisation details into the database and then, on another view, I have a data grid to show what they have entered to enable the user to update the content when needed.

which leads me to my question. So far I have validated my commands so that when certain fields are empty, then the button will not be active but once they have been entered, they will be activated. Like so;

```
           private ICommand showAddCommand;
    public ICommand ShowAddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.showAddCommand == null)
            {
                this.showAddCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SaveFormExecute, this.SaveFormCanExecute);//i => this.InsertOrganisation()
            }

            return this.showAddCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool SaveFormCanExecute()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrganisationName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Postcode)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MobileNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PracticeStructure) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(PracticeType) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RegistrationNumber); 
    }

    private void SaveFormExecute()
    {
        InsertOrganisations();
    }

  Xaml:
  <Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="18" x:Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Command="{Binding ShowAddCommand}"/>
```

But what I was hoping to achieve is that, once a user has entered in 1 organisation into the database, then the command doesn't become active altogether and prevents the user from entering another organisation by accident. the purpose is to only allow 1 organisation to be added, no more or no less.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, so i post it as a comment. I think what you need is per form validation. Have a look at this [article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/01/bindinggroups-for-total-view-validation/).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Well, my fields have been validated using attribute validation so that's not the problem. I just want a way of being able to validate my command so it only allows one row of data to be entered (within the database), possible use a flag? But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you bind the IsEnabled property to a property you call bool HasOrganisation {return mOrganisation.Count > 0;} And you raise this if the organisation property is changed. Its hard giving you a good answer without more information about your code. At best give us a very small runnable example of what you want to do.

Comment: Ill give that a go thanks. I've used this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat) as my source of validation for my text fields and used EF for my commands to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.  1), I'd recommend editing your RelayCommand to take an Action as follows:

```
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
```

This may not help your immediate issue, but it will make your code more reusable, as you'll be able to bind certain elements from your View as parameters in your ICommand for both CanExecute testing and Execution (or if you won't require this, just pass null as the object parameter in the ICommand.Execute and don't bind anything to CommandParameter in the View)

Furthermore, in your RelayCommand, make sure you are overriding CanExecuteChanged as follows:

```
    public override event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

This will trigger your ICommand to recheck CanExecute when changes are made by the user (and is most likely the piece that you're missing).

Finally, once this is done, it's just a matter of including your criteria in CanExecute (either from the CommandParameter OR from something in your VM).

I hope this helps.